# cfinvoke with two different methods

Tags: coldfusion

I have two cfinvoke, I need to use them in one cfm

```
<cfinvoke component="cfc/queries" method="getProjects"  searchString="#Session.Auth.pref_name#" view="#Session.Auth.view#" returnvariable="Projects"> 
<cfinvoke component="cfc/queries" method="projectDetails"  searchString="#URL.id#" projectsuffix="#URL.suffix#" returnvariable="Details">
```

to return two queries, but when I coding like this way it's not working.
I'm still new to the ColdFusion and I don't know how to fix that.

Comment: What does "not working" mean? Is there an error?  Also, watch out using anything from an untrusted source like `URL`. That's very ea\sily injectible.

Comment: no there is no error but the method (getProjects) not return any project

Comment: Are `getProjects` and `projectDetails` inside the same component? And does that component require an `init` function?

Comment: And what version of ColdFusion?

Comment: yes they are in same component, and no require for an init function

Comment: ColdFusion version 11

Comment: If `getProjects()` doesn't return results, what does that page look like?

Comment: Check the getProperties() functions for the sql queries it is using. Run that query in your db if you are getting any results.

Comment: Before trying the query, try to `cfdump cfabort` the `Projects` variable to see if you are getting anything from the first call. As you said, that variable is a query object, so you should be getting a cfdump of the query variable with zero records. Else you will get an error message if the call was not successful. In that case verify the cfc path.

Comment: 1) You can dump the argument in getProjects & projectDetails in these function itself , then you can understand whether the functions called properly or not. 
2). Also  put dump & abort Projects & Details variable. If it's return undefined error then you have to check  getProjects & projectDetails function return anything or not. You have give cfreturn in that functions. 

If both the options are good then you have to show your both method code here. Then we can find the reason for issue.

Answer (score -1):

Since both functions are in the same CFC, you wouldn't want to use `cfinvoke` since it recreates the object each time it's called. Instead, use a `new` or a `createObject()`.

```
<cfset queries = new location.to.cfc.queriesCFC()>
```

Then you can just reference the functions.

```
<cfset Projects = 
    queries.getProjects(
        searchString=session.Auth.pref_name, 
        view = session.Auth.view
    )
>
<cfset Details = 
    queries.projectDetails(
        searchString=url.id, 
        projectsuffix=url.suffix
    )
>
```

You may want to sanitize `url.id` and `url.suffix` before you pass them through. This will help with injection issues.

What does `getProjects()` do?

Comment: function to list all the projects

Comment: Can you provide an example of the code it contains? Does it have a `return`?

Answer (score -1):

We can write like as below,

```
<!--- Object creation --->
<cfset query = CreateObject("component", "cfc.queries")/>

<!--- Function call --->
<cfset Projects = query.getProjects( searchString = session.Auth.pref_name, view = session.Auth.view )>
<cfset Details = query.projectDetails( searchString = session.Auth.pref_name, view = session.Auth.view )>
```